# How to group array data by date

Tags: php, arrays, json, sorting, slim

I use an API where the endpoint results look like :

```
[
    {
        placeId: 1,
        startDateIso: "2015-11-26T12:00:00+0100",
    },
    {
        placeId: 1,
        startDateIso: "2015-11-26T13:00:00+0100",
    },
    {
        placeId: 1,
        startDateIso: "2015-11-27T10:00:00+0100",
    },
    {
        placeId: 1,
        startDateIso: "2015-11-27T11:00:00+0100",
    },
]
```

How can I sort this JSON array for an output like this :

```
{
   [
       {
           placeId: 1,
           startDateIso: "2015-11-26T12:00:00+0100",
       },
       {
           placeId: 1,
           startDateIso: "2015-11-26T13:00:00+0100",
       }
   ],

   [
       {
           placeId: 1,
           startDateIso: "2015-11-27T10:00:00+0100",
       },
       {
           placeId: 1,
           startDateIso: "2015-11-27T11:00:00+0100",
       }
   ]
}
```

I want to sort the data by date and create an array for each.

Comment: How do you use the API? Where and how do you want to do the sorting?

Comment: Show your code if you want help .. Just the required output is not enough ..

Comment: Your desired JSON output is invalid as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following

```
// Sample input
$input = array(array('startDateIso'=>'2015-11-26T12:00:00+010', 'placeId'=>1),
               array('startDateIso'=>'2015-11-26T12:00:00+010', 'placeId'=>2),
               array('startDateIso'=>'2015-11-27T12:00:00+010', 'placeId'=>3),
               array('startDateIso'=>'2015-11-27T13:00:00+010', 'placeId'=>4));

$output = array();

foreach($input as $element) {
    $date = date('d.m.Y', strtotime($element['startDateIso'])); // Truncate time

    $output[$date][] = $element; // Group using associate array, key is the date
}

$result = array_values($output); // Converts assoicate array to array

echo json_encode($result);
```

Output :

```
[
     [
          {
               "startDateIso":"2015-11-26T12:00:00+010",
               "placeId":1
          },
          {
               "startDateIso":"2015-11-26T12:00:00+010",
               "placeId":2
          }
     ],
     [
          {
               "startDateIso":"2015-11-27T12:00:00+010",
               "placeId":3
          },
          {
               "startDateIso":"2015-11-27T13:00:00+010",
               "placeId":4
          }
     ]
]
```

Comment: Hi @bltstray if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.